# two space tab is the safest one?

Tags: html, syntax, indentation

[Bumped](http://codeguide.co/) into such a statement:

> Use soft tabs with two spaces—they're the only way to guarantee code renders the same in any environment.

Is that true? (and why?)

Comment: Sorry to issue a close vote, but this question has more to it than meets the eye. The battle of tabs vs spaces (and yes, how many) is sometimes fought religiously, and the best common ground is: Use what the code already uses, that you edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not true and everyone has an own best practice related to editor settings and code formatting.

I think that two spaces is just to few, because in long source codes with several nesting levels it is much easier for me to distinguish between different indentation levels if there are ate least four spaces used as tab width.